# Can't download emails from hotmail to Mozilla Thunderbird since a week ago

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird

Since a week ago I can't download my emails from Hotmail to Thunderbird but I can send new ones.
When I try to download Thunderbird says "Downloading 1 of 5...." and then a msgbox appears and says something like "Server unavailable. 21"

I have a second Hotmail account that works fine with the same settings.

Comment: Qs: Are you working with outlook? You have the outlook tag, but in your post you talk about Hotmail, which you don't need Outlook for of course. Are your accounts Exchange accounts? POP/IMAP?

Comment: @FLonLon Outlook is also the current name for what once were the hotmail services.

Comment: @FLonLon Exactly! That's why I add the Outlook tag.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, we mainly discuss the problems related to the outlook client with the tag of "Microsoft Outlook".

I noticed that you have configured your Hotmail account on Thunderbird. Do configure your account as a POP account? If so, please try to configure it as an IMAP account to check if there are any differences.

Meanwhile, in order to further check whether it is a problem with Thunderbird client, please configure your account in other mail clients, such as outlook and mail, to check whether they work normally.

If the same is true on other clients, it may be your account problem. It is suggested that you could contact Microsoft online support for help with account problems.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Comment: Yes, I change to IMAP and works ok. The bad. I have this email since 2001, so I have a ton of emails in it. Try to download that amount of emails with 15Mbps ISP is a pain. For the same reason I didn't try another apps. What I was doing before change to IMAP was making a backup of the Thunderbird profile folder so Thunderbird download the latest ones. I also had some local folders with local rules and now I lost everything. The emails are there but all in the same folder as is in the web.

Comment: It is unfortunate that although it helps to configure IMAP account, it brings you these troubles. Considering the different synchronization of POP and IMAP accounts in Thunderbird, it is suggested that you could post in Thunderbird related forums, or contact Thunderbird's technical support engineers to for advice on how to recover your data or better.

Comment: Hi@E_Blue, just checking if your issue has any update, if you don't have any other questions , it would be better to mark the helpful post.

Comment: @Jade The post solved one problem and created others, so I just marked as helpful. If I mark it as solved somebody else can think that is a whole solution when is not. At least I see it that way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Hope your problem can be solved soon!